# Getting values of an object after iteration

Tags: javascript

I have this object i copied from my console

```
Object { input_name: "hi", input_type: "world", input_number: "200" }
```

which i had earlier put together this way

```
 var post = {
    input_name: name,
    input_type: type,
    input_number: number
    };
    console.log(post);
```

I am passing the data as an array to another function which does the inserting to a mongodb. I need to get the first,second and third values in seperate variables in order to be inserted into the database.

I have tried this

```
  for (var key in post) {
var one = post[key];
console.log(one);
break;
    }
```

and have only just got the first value. How can i hold the three values each in its own variable?.

Comment: The order of iteration of the keys in a `for...in` loop is not guaranteed. So don't do that. You know what the properties are called, so access them `post[input_name]` or `post.input_name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to have new variable per each value. Just access object properties by it's keys:

```
console.log(post.input_name);
console.log(post.input_type);
console.log(post.input_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the break from your loop.. your code should be:

```
for (var key in post) {
    var one = post[key];
    console.log(one);    
}
```

Comment: The order of iteration is not guaranteed, however.

Comment: yea, thats a thing though